# build definition – only empty queue

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

If I am creating a build definition, I can’t choose a Default agent queue. Not so long ago, I can create build definition which includes the default queue. I don’t know what the change was, that it doesn’t work anymore. If I go to edit a correct created build definition and then I try again to create a definition, I can choose the default queue. What is the reason for that?

Editing an existing build definition before creating isn’t the solution, because I have many projects and some have a correct build definition and some have no build Definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are meaning the **Default agent queue** such as below during the creation of build definition [image]

The queue that's attached to the pool that contains the agents you want to run this definition. You can first double check the status of your agent pool. Make sure everything is OK.

[image: image description here]

And even after you created the definition, you can still change the queue in **General** , try to change the queue here to identify if there's still empty queue.

[image]

Comment: Yes I mean the Default agent queue. If I go to the "manage" Site for the queue, I see the the correct default queue, like in your picture.

Comment: It's really weird. Did this phenomenon only occurs with your account ? Could you edit the queue in the general ' How about the new created team project not the exist project?

Comment: Yes this occurs only with my account. No there is the queue also empty.

Comment: Then it may related to the Permissions. You can ask your TFS admin to double check if you have enough permissions related to build.

Comment: You are right. My user was missing in the group "Build Administrators". Now its working.